# Elastic Search API pagination - How do you include the search_after parameter in Search using esapi code?

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I'm using elastic search api for golang and have some questions on how to implement the [search_after approach](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/paginate-search-results.html#search-after) of paginating through the official esapi...

Simple pagination using a startFrom page index is currently implemented but obviously has limitations.  The grid I'm The User can always refine their search, but there is the possibility that a user may click through hundreds of pages until they find what they're looking for...smh...  I can craft an error asking the user to refine the search, but would like to have a more robust solution.

We've managed to use request JSON in order to get what we want, but now we need to implement a solution in code.  We can get the index id's and just need to send it back to the UI for subsequent requests.

Looking through the [API docs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch@v0.0.0/esapi), I'm not able to find how to deal with this *search_after* parameter or the PIT parameter in the Search type in the API code.  ***Do these parameters need to be handled within the query string? Is this even possible using this API?***  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    res, err := helper.EsClient.Search(
       helper.EsClient.Search.WithContext(ctx),
       helper.EsClient.Search.WithIndex(indexSearch),
       helper.EsClient.Search.WithQuery(qstring),  //"(Foo.foo.clientId: 1)"
       helper.EsClient.Search.WithSource(source),
       helper.EsClient.Search.WithTrackTotalHits(true),
       helper.EsClient.Search.WithPretty(),
       ...
       helper.EsClient.Search.WithSize(pageSize),
      helper.EsClient.Search.WithSort(sort),    //@timestamp:desc
)
```

**EDIT** corrected the URL to the pkg.go.dev esapi page

Comment: Removed 'esapi' tag as that is for Owasp's 'Enterprise Security API' project.

Comment: @avgvstvs thanks! I didn't realize the project had an overlapping name with Elastic's official api.